# Populate 3 selection lists using queries on the same entity, using Symfony2 buildForm()

Tags: symfony

I have an entity Machine which has a relation MM with other entity Piece. The pieces can be from 3 different types. Currently the form Machine is built with a selection list in which the whole array collection Machine.pieces is fetched. My idea is to build 3 *different* selection lists with a subset of Machine.pieces each.

I have tried two different approaches but I have no been able to accomplish it.

1. Use a `MachineRepository` class where a method

   ```
   public function findPiecesByPieceType($pieceTypeID)
   ```

returns the proper `query->getResult()`.

Then I add a choiceType in MachineType but I am not able to populate it from `MachineController`. I have used `$form->get('pieces')->setData($arrcollectPieces)` and other methods to add choices but I always get error.

How could I add choices from the controller to a Form?

2. In the form I use a queryBuilder

   ```
       ->add('pieces', EntityType::class, array(
               'label' => 'label_pieces',
               'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Piece',
               'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                   return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                           ->where('p.pieceType = :pieceType')
                           ->setParameter('pieceType', 1);
               },
           )
       )
   ```

this works but when I try to add more queryBuilders (`->add('pieces2'`... and so on) I have the error because

*Neither the property `pieces2` nor one of the methods `getPiecess2()`, `pieces2()`, `isPieces2()`, `hasPieces2()`, `__get()` exist and have public access in class `AppBundle\Entity\Machine`.*

How can I use the various queryBuilders not bounded to a method name in that way?

Maybe both approaches are incorrect and I should solve this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

How to make it using 1.

In `MachineController` forget setData(), instead turn the `arrayCollection` into 2 arrays `(arKeys, arValues)` and send them to the form as the 3rd parameter in `createForm()`.

```
$form = $this->createForm(<type>, <data>, 
    array ('p_keys' => array(...), 'p_values' => array(...)));
```

From `MachineType.ConfigureOptions()` we can fetch them

```
$resolver->setDefined(["p_keys",'p_values']);
```

and they will be available in `MachineType.buildForm()`

```
$options['p_keys'];
$options['p_values'];
```